# Scheme filter with a function as a predicate

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm sorry if I'm opening up too many Scheme questions, but this has been bugging me for a while now.

So I have a function( say pair-scorer)  that takes a list of pairs of strings as parameters and scores them according to how close they are ( 2 points for the same character, -1 points for a different character)

so for example

```
(pair-scorer '(("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ccc") ("aaa" "aab")))
```

will return `'(-3 6 3)`

I also have a max function which will take the maximum of this list of numbers

eg

```
(max-list '(-3 6 3))

>6
```

Now here's the problem. I need to create a filter to take in the list of pairs of strings ie.`'(("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ccc") ("aaa" "aab"))` and return only the pair (or pairs) that yields the maximum value when run through the scoring function.

How do I implement this filter?
Hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have a `score` function that can find the score of a single pair (this must be called in `pair-scorer`). Try this:

```
(argmax score '(("aaa" "bbb") ("ccc" "ccc") ("aaa" "aab")))
```

The trick here was using [`argmax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._argmax%29%29), which receives a function to be applied to each element in the list and finds the element for which that function returns the maximum value.

Be aware that `argmax` will return a single element even if there are several with the same maximum value, if that's a problem you'll have to write your own function, but it's easy in terms of the existing procedures, and using [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29):

```
(define (max-elements lst)
  (let ((maximum (max-list (pair-scorer lst))))
    (filter (lambda (pair) (= (score pair) maximum))
            lst)))
```

The above will return a list with all the elements which have the maximum score. If there's just one, then the list will contain a single element.

Comment: No problem :) . Please be aware that `argmax` will return a single element even if there are several with the same maximum value, I hope that's ok

Comment: Hmmm that's not ok actually :/ Any work around for this?

Comment: There isn't a built-in function for this case, but it's easy to write a solution in terms of existing procedures; check my updated answer